# How does the snap math node work?

Tags: mathematics

Pretty much the title, I'm pretty confused and the blender documentation doesn't help much : "Round the input value to down to the nearest integer multiple of Increment"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does what it says on the tin.. :) .. it winds up being a staircase function:

[image]

.. with the rise and tread both being the 'Increment'. Here, shown with increments of 2, 1, and 2/3.

For any input X, the output will be X, rounded down to the nearest whole-number multiple of 'Increment'.

Thanks again to @Rich Sedman for this way of visualising functions..

[image]

Because of the great geometry nodes you can also watch easily the snap values with this node setup:

[image]

Just change the B-values and/or the x/y offset values and watch what happens.

As @batFINGER points out, in Python, it could be: `increment * (x // increment)`

Comment: So say for example for an increment of 1, X = 1. Will Snap(X) be 0 or 1?

Comment: Look at the picture : offset is 1 - x is 1 - snapx is 0 so the answer is: it is 0

Comment: It should be 1, bearing in mind, in floating-point world, you can't necessarily rely on there being any such thing as 1.

Comment: Alright, im gonna have to digest this for a bit. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Robin, Scriptwise Is this  `n * (x // n)` where `n` is the increment?

Comment: @batFINGER just tested with dodgy range of floats in the console.. seems to be just the ticket.. (of course you could have done it in 0.500000001 of the time) :)